# Send MultiSelect data to Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to help with this code:

- I am sending information from a table to the modal and in that table
  there will be data from the groups separated by commas
- I would like it to be selected in the modal in MultiSelect like the
  example of low users.
- The bottom MultiSelect works perfectly but I don't know how to do it
  on that first model.
- Model was removed from this site [loudev](http://loudev.com/)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSJcV.jpg)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://loudev.com/css/multi-select.css" />
  <script src="https://loudev.com/js/jquery.multi-select.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr class="text-center">
            <th class="d-none"></th>
            <th>Página</th>
            <th>Cód. Página</th>
            <th>Tipo</th>
            <th>Grupos</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td class="d-none">
              <input type="radio" id="customRadio" name="customRadio" data-envia-id="1" data-envia-pagina="Nome Exemplo" data-envia-codpagina="Situação Exemplo" data-envia-tipo="Pagina" data-envia-grupo="Suporte, Comercial" data-envia-usuarios="usuario1, usuario2"
                data-envia-observacao="Observacao Exemplo">
            </td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td class="d-none">
              <input type="radio" id="customRadio" name="customRadio" data-envia-id="1" data-envia-pagina="Nome Exemplo" data-envia-codpagina="Situação Exemplo" data-envia-tipo="22" data-envia-grupo="Suporte, Comercial" data-envia-observacao="Observacao Exemplo">
            </td>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /Modal para cadastro de contratos -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="Modal-Editar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"> Realizar Alterações</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <form method="POST" action="teste.php">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 form-group has-feedback">
                <input type="text" name="pagina" id="RecebPagina" class="form-control has-feedback-left" placeholder="Nome da Página" required>
                <span class="fa fa-check-square-o form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 form-group has-feedback">
                <select id="RecebGrupo" class="custom-select text-center" multiple>
                  <option></option>
                  <option value="Suporte">Suporte</option>
                  <option value="Comercial">Comercial</option>
                  <option value="Agenda">Agenda</option>
                  <option value="Financeiro">Financeiro</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group has-feedback">
                <select id="RecebUsuarios2" class="custom-select" multiple>
                  <option></option>
                  <option value="usuario1">usuario1</option>
                  <option value="usuario2">usuario2</option>
                  <option value="usuario3">usuario3</option>
                  <option value="usuario3">usuario3</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name='btnValue' value='btnEdiPermissoes'>Editar</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.modal-content').resizable({
      //alsoResize: ".modal-dialog",
      minHeight: 300,
      minWidth: 300
    });
    $('.modal-dialog').draggable();

    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
      $(this).find('.modal-body').css({
        'max-height': '100%'
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.modal-dialog').draggable();

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
    //Função para marcar o checkbox ao clicar na linha: ondblclick
    $("table tr").on("dblclick", function() {
      $(this).children().children()[0].click();
      $('#Modal-Editar').modal('show');

      $.each($("input[name='customRadio']:checked"), function() {
        VarId = $(this).data('envia-id');
        VarPagina = $(this).data('envia-pagina');
        VarCodpagina = $(this).data('envia-codpagina');
        VarTipo = $(this).data('envia-tipo');
        VarUsuarios = $(this).data('envia-usuarios');
        VarGrupo = $(this).data('envia-grupo');
        VarObservacao = $(this).data('envia-observacao');
        $('#RecebId').val(VarId);
        $('#RecebId2').html(VarId);
        $('#RecebPagina').val(VarPagina);
        $('#RecebCodpagina').val(VarCodpagina);
        $('#RecebTipo').html(VarTipo);
        $('#RecebUsuarios').html(VarUsuarios);
        $('#RecebObservacao').val(VarObservacao);

        $('#RecebGrupo option').each(function(index) {
          var str = VarGrupo;
          var substr = str.split(', ');

          for (var i = 0; i < substr.length; i++) {
            if (substr[i] == $(this).val()) {
              //$("option:selected", this).attr();
              $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
              //$(this).attr('selected', true);
              //$(this).addClass('ms-elem-selectable ms-hover ms-selected').show();
              //$(this).addClass('ms-hover').show();
              //$(this).addClass('ms-selected').show();

              //$(this).Attr('hidden');
              //$(this).Attr('id', '-190140734-selection');

            }
          }
        });

        $('#RecebUsuarios2 option').each(function(index) {
          var str = VarUsuarios;
          var substr = str.split(', ');

          for (var i = 0; i < substr.length; i++) {
            if (substr[i] == $(this).val()) {
              //$("option:selected", this).attr();
              $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
              //$(this).attr('selected', true);
              //$(this).addClass('ms-elem-selectable ms-hover ms-selected').show();
              //$(this).addClass('ms-hover').show();
              //$(this).addClass('ms-selected').show();

              //$(this).Attr('hidden');
              //$(this).Attr('id', '-190140734-selection');
            }
          }
        });

      });


    });
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // MultiSelect Cadastro de Grupo
    $('#Selected-GrupoCad').multiSelect();
    // MultiSelect Editar Grupo
    $('#RecebGrupo').multiSelect();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: From a first, very quick glance, you are using multiple occurrances of the same `id` on your radio input. An `id` is a unique selector and should only ever be used once, because if you are using any script logic with that `id`, then you will only ever get the *first* instance of that `id`.

Comment: Don't include jquery UI twice

Comment: I really need help, would I have some code that I can use? Thank you very much in advance.